# Loop Print Transactions in table

Tags: php, api, for-loop

I am using this API: http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/txs/1ERfGndGG4DD1XUzVrnAUqKBPDTu3zZV1z.

I want to print the transaction and time in a table of first 10 transactions. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Please include your code and an example of your expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more or less what you were needing to do.

```
$url='http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/txs/1ERfGndGG4DD1XUzVrnAUqKBPDTu3zZV1z';

/* Get the data in json format */
$json=json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );

/* Find the relevant start node */
$txs=$json->data->txs;

/* iterate through nodes */
foreach( $txs as $i => $tx ){
    if( $i <=10 ){
        echo $tx->tx . ' ' . $tx->time_utc . '<br />';
    }
}


Output
------
a22919e4408eccacd879db7c7607dfa9752ad4af41c60e5b6419f5235afaa5d2 2017-06-17T00:52:40Z
5ea629c7543b88e92b294781c3c0960c706929250542de30b97f32f5e42e7933 2017-06-16T15:49:19Z
6f06b9e2fcf1df03b762faaa34e7933ca419facd0a86fb7af0f9ff4de0be824d 2017-06-16T11:53:58Z
226efdc2c2a5ef6bd761dad163cbce517291fcb71b2e990abcaaeca11065778f 2017-06-16T10:34:08Z
92e161ad894d77613986f7b2c54401a7df33902d24ce0c3535d78b8476e4e369 2017-06-16T03:22:29Z
e88de037337897d4246ba609c85804e65688d4e4955ee82c02e5acd766083144 2017-06-16T01:43:08Z
87fcffc5f117f99c7a3b6982f03965d859c1fefee97ff5cebb5d240c01105b78 2017-06-15T17:38:51Z
fc67f626f6533270e3d75131ae082521f68aef0aaeb43fd3e9d8822590c6b4b6 2017-06-15T17:17:11Z
34d976ae3b5b02be894751d9d9534312ace49f211d0d0417b392732c9f2a3dc5 2017-06-15T06:13:27Z
f6caa65c1f7acd4a6c2a1a1428529ce11f6ff91f1b69bf9658a2b0480cae1eb1 2017-06-15T02:12:22Z
ae3db67975eba26d2381428ccdb6d7ae6a9c71d259402d063b9537df564f6ef9 2017-06-14T10:26:25Z
```

Or, as a HTML table

```
$url='http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/txs/1ERfGndGG4DD1XUzVrnAUqKBPDTu3zZV1z';
$json=json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
$txs=$json->data->txs;

$html=array('<table border=1>');
foreach( $txs as $i => $tx ){
    if( $i <=10 ){
        $html[]='<tr>';/* ADD HYPERLINK BELOW IN HREF ATTRIBUTE */
        $html[]='<td><a href="" target="_blank">'.$tx->tx.'</a></td>';
        $html[]='<td>'.$tx->time_utc.'</td>';
        $html[]='</tr>';
    }
}
$html[]='</table>';

echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
```

Or, to show all properties for each transaction you could do

```
$url='http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/txs/1ERfGndGG4DD1XUzVrnAUqKBPDTu3zZV1z';
$json=json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );
$txs=$json->data->txs;


$keys=array_keys( get_object_vars( $txs[0] ) );

$html=array('<table border=1>');
foreach( $txs as $i => $tx ){
    if( $i <=10 ){
        $html[]='<tr>';
        foreach( $keys as $key )$html[]='<td>'.$tx->$key.'</td>';
        $html[]='</tr>';
    }
}
$html[]='</table>';
echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
```

Comment: How can i add hyperlink on the transaction?

Comment: Not sure what the correct URL would be but I have edited the code to include a hyperlink - add the relevant URL where it says

Comment: No worries, i did it. Thanks :)